# How can I return the data from AxiosResponse?

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I am new to NestJS and I am trying to use the `HttpModule` which incorporates `axios`. The problem I have is that I don't know how to return the data from the response. I am getting some `Subscription` object. For now I could only make it console.log like this:

```js
this.httpService
      .get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
      .subscribe((e) => console.log(e.data));
```

This works fine, but when I try to return the data it returns the `Subscriber` object instead.

```js
this.httpService
      .get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
      .subscribe((e) => e.data);
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank You.

Comment: Look into Observables. If it helps, in this case they work somewhat like promises, so you can't just assign the result of `subscribe` to something. Its asynchronous.

Comment: Yes it returns a Promise, but when resolved it returns the same object. I can only console.log it in the `subscribe` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the answer provided by Michal, or you can return observables and work with those (as Nest will take care of the subscription later). Returning the observable would look something like this:

```js
return this.httpService
  .get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  .pipe(
    map((res) => res.data)
  );
```

Either of these approaches work fine. It just depends on how comfortable with RxJS you are

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using it like this:

```js
const res = this.httpService
      .get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
      .toPromise()
    
console.log(res.data)
```

Comment: toPromise is getting deprecated, you can refer to the rxjs docs on this...